# How to count positive electrical pulses?

Tags: led, digital

I have a device that has one blinking LED.

I want to count the number of blinks. I planned to do it using Arduino. I will connect two terminals of LED input to Arduino digital input pins, and I will count the number of positive voltage pulses

I just want to know if it is possible? and if yes then can you please hint the code for the same?

Comment: be aware that an LED can be turned on by applying Vcc to the LED, but it can also be turned on by applying 0 V ... it all depends how the LED is connected in the circuit

Comment: Look in the Arduino IDE.  There is an example called "State Change Example"  That's what you need.

Comment: Trying to use the voltage over the LED might not work, because it only changes from 0V to the forward voltage of about 2V (+/- some tenth). Use jsotola's comment and use the side that gets switched, this could as well be at the current limiting resistor.

Answer (score 1):

You should not count the number of pulses, but the number of transition from 0 to VCC volts or VCC to 0 volts (called rising resp. falling edge).

If you don't want to solder, you can also use a light dependent resistor (LDR) very close by the LED to measure the difference in brightness. See also chrisl's remark below.

The counting you can do manually (in a loop, check as often as possible or needed), or by setting up a timer to check for either rising or falling edges.

I will give the pseudo code so you can figure out the actual code:

```
bool _ldrPin;
unsigned long int _counter;


setup()
{
   // Set Serial
   Serial.begin(9600);

   // Set LDR
   setAnalogPin(X, INPUT);
   _ldrPin = readAnalog(X);
}

loop()
{
    if (!_ldrPin && readAnalog(X) == HIGH)
    {
        // Rising edge, increase counter
        _counter++;
        Serial.Write(_counter);
        _ldrPin = true;
    }
    else if (ldrPin && readAnalog(X) == LOW)
    {
       // Falling edge, reset status
        _ldrPin = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no "light diode resistor". I think you mean a light dependent resistor. Though I wouldn't suggest an LDR for blinking measurement, they are rather slow. Depending on the blinking frequency this could very well be too slow. A photo transistor is a better choice (a phototransistor is basically a diode in reverse, which get's conductable by light), it can work very fast.

Comment: Sir, I am planning to solder. But I think I have to solder both the wires from the led. I thin voltage difference is relative, so how do I compare the difference between voltage(when LED glows) using digital pins.

Comment: @chrisl Thanks for the notification (I mean indeed light dependent resistor). I never tried a photo resistor (added your name, upvoted your comment).

Comment: @SSR At least both wires should be connected to something otherwise you don't have a (closed) circuit, at least not with the LED in it. For comparing you might use an opamp but that's probably worth a different question.

Answer (score 1):

## Detecting the LED Pulses

You want to detect each LED pulse. For this you will need **edge detection code**. There is an Arduino example built into the IDE and information describing the function here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/StateChangeDetection

To add to the Arduino explanation, you can either detect the rising edge (ie. the transition from a LOW to a HIGH) or the falling edge (ie. the transition from a HIGH to a LOW). I personally prefer the following code to detect a rising edge. In simple terms the code can be translated to this:

```
if ( (lastLedState == LOW) && (ledState == HIGH) )
```

where `ledState` would be assigned by a `digitalRead` and `lastLedState` would record the value of `ledState` at the end of the loop function (ie. just before it reads in the led states again).

## Full Code

Now if we optimise the above statement and put it into context:

```
unsigned long int pulseCounter = 0;
const int LedInput = 3;    // Digital input 3
bool ledState = 0;
bool lastLedState = 0;

void setup() {
    
}

void loop() {
    ledState = digitalRead(LedInput);
    
    // If the LED turns ON
    if (ledState && !lastLedState)
    {
        // Increment your counter
        pulseCount++;
    }
    
    // Update LED flag
    lastLedState = ledState;
}
```